# System requrements for running kubuntu 15.04 with kde plasma?

Tags: kubuntu, kde

my laptop model is-
Dell Inspiron 15 3543,
intel 5th gen 1.9 GHZ,
4 GB ram, 
intel intregrated ghraphics.
Can i run KDE plasma on my laptop?
what are the minimum system requirements of running KDE Plasma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think they are officially specified for Kubuntu 15.04. However, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements should work as a rule of thumb. There, they also state:

> Simply try Ubuntu CD as a LiveCD first to check the hardware works
>   You could just try with a Kubuntu 15.04 LiveCD to find out if it works on your system.